# LoadError: cannot load such file -- carrierwave/mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> Log --trace
>   % rake rails:update:bin --trace

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- carrierwave/mongoid
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/Users/Sean/Desktop/PROJECTS/Renascence/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
/Users/Sean/Desktop/PROJECTS/Renascence/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

全く、直し方がわからないのですが、どうすればよろしいですか。

Answer (score 1):

`bundle exec rake ...` または `bin/rake ...` としてみたらどうなりますか？